# Visualforce reading field as an object

Tags: datetime

I've been banging my head against a wall for this and can't seem to figure out this error. VF seems to be reading my field as an object.

Here is my code

```
LineitemNumber: <apex:outputText value="{!(NOW()-object.LastModifiedDate)*24*60*60}"></apex:outputText>
```

Here is the error: **"Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Object"**

How is VF reading the field as an object?

Comment: Did you literally name your variable "Object"?

Comment: I am not, I'm getting it from a controller. from my controller, it is called lineItems. What is weird is that I tested it with another object that I pull LastModifiedDate from and it works just fine. It just won't read with this object.

Comment: I found something similar in this link, except it is with a different error: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9482/errors-using-ispickval-on-visualforce-page

Comment: What's the data type of LineItems? It sounds like a List...

Comment: Maybe that is what I am not understanding. LineItems is the object but when I think datatype, I'm thinking LastModifiedDate is the field with datatype of DateTime.

Comment: The data type of lineitems should be some sort of record. For example, in your controller, you might have something like `public OpportunityLineItem lineItems { get; set; }` or something like that. Knowing the type of data would help us figure out why it's broke.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, I just went over this with salesforce support and it looked like odd behavior. It worked at times when we saved it, and didn't at other times when we commented out some lines. What's odd is that those lines were different objects that had nothing to do with this one. I ended up getting rid of those lines just to get this to work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This code works in my org:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    {!(NOW()-Account.LastModifiedDate)*86400}
</apex:page>
```

(It also works with apex:outputText).

Check the data type of the variable you're referencing, and make sure you're referencing the correct variable.