# Conditional rendering using IF in Visualforce Template

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, email-template, visualforce-template

I have a VF template where I need to vary the closing part of the mail(after 'Best Regards') based on a particular Picklist field on the case object.

Eg if Custom_field__c ='ML' then the closing part of the email should be - ABC
if Custom_field__c ='SS' then the closing part of the email should be - CFG and a few similiar conditions. My code here does not seem to work

```
 <messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!relatedTo.Subject}, 

        {!relatedTo.CaseNumber} {!relatedTo.ThreadId__c}" 
        recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Case">
        <messaging:htmlEmailBody >

      <html>      
   <body>
<STYLE type="text/css">   
td.content{font-size: 14px; font-face: Verdana; text-align: left}  
</style>

  <td class="content">       
 <br> Should you have any further enquiries, you may simply reply to this email.</br>      

   <apex:repeat var="cs" value="{!relatedTo}">
   <apex:outputpanel rendered="{If(ISPICKVAL(cs.Custom_field__c ,'Maersk Line')true,false)}">

      <br>Kind Regards,</br>
          Msl 

        </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:repeat>             
      </td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
</font>
</body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Tushar, relatedTo is a single record, not a list. Merge fields always start with `{!` and end with `}`. You forgot the `!`. Also, you don't need an "IF" statement here:

```
rendered="{!ISPICKVAL(relatedTo.Custom_field__c ,'Maersk Line')}"
```

Comment: Good catch totally missed it.

Comment: @gopal1007 Yes, ISPICKVAL is only for picklists; I used it under the impression from your code that it was actually a picklist.

Comment: It is a picklist field. But I am not sure why it is returning a text tho!

Comment: just a note that visualforce appears to treat picklists like text - so pickval throws an error "Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Text".  This behavior is supported by [this sfse post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9482/errors-using-ispickval-on-visualforce-page) - so just using a regular == comparison operator instead is working

Answer (score 0):

As `RelatedTo` refer to a single object so we don't need `apex:repeat` here.

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!ISPICKVAL(relatedTo.Custom_field__c ,'Maersk Line')}">

      <br>Kind Regards,</br>
          MaerskLine 

</apex:outputpanel> // use same for others as well
```

Comment: I have tried your answer and it still doenst seem to work

Comment: @gopal1007 what are the output you are getting here?